# Design decisions for ASP.NET data access layer

Tags: c#, dry, separation-of-concerns

I have a set of static database access layer classes that do CRUD operations on a vehicle, a dealer and a large tracking record. These objects can be fairly sizeable in their memory consumption due to notes being recorded against them, etc. Let's call this set of classes "A".

In addition, I have another static class called Lookups that performs read-only operations for the purposes of populating DropDownLists. Very very lean objects are returned (just an ID and a Text field) - let's call this class "B"

The methods in class "B" read from the same tables as those in set "A".

Some of the code in B looks similar to what is already in "A", except returning smaller objects.

I'm violating the DRY principle in B but only because I don't want to return large objects for the purposes of populating a dropdown list. I want this system to be scalable so am going easy on the RAM. But I can't help thinking there might be a better way, design wise.

What would you recommend?

For the next project I'll be using the Entity Framework, but this is old-school ADO.NET hand-coded SqlConnection and SqlCommand objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have one repository for each entity of your business logic. Something like this:

```
// dealing only with Vehicle operations
public interface IVehicleReposity {
    // Operations..
}

public class VehicleReposity: IVehicleReposity {
   // Impementiong operations and 
   // calling your static methods
}
```

This will allow you to change your business logic any time you want. As you will be able to call you static methods, Entity Framework or Nhibernate, if you want some day..

In that case you don't will repeat yourself, and you will be able to work in the Dependency Injection easlly.

Comment: Hi Mata, I currently have VehicleDA, DealerDA and HireDA classes at the moment, each of which deal with the CRUD operations for the respective entities.

Comment: I meant to add, DA = Data Access. In addition, I also have a LookupDA that reads from the same DB tables as those objects. Because the LookupDA reads from the same tables, this means there is some duplicate code. It's a DRY violation but yet I think it's the most memory efficient. Yet I'm fighting myself thinking there's a smell somewhere